# how to access dom in ember 4.12 controller

Tags: ember.js

I have a input box in DOM, and monitor the input value in controller, and there's another button, if the input value is changed, I want to change the button title or properties accordingly, how can I do this in controller?

test.hbs

```
<input type="text" value="somevalue" {{on "click" this.updatevalue}}/>
<button type="button" id="test">test</button>
```

test.js

```
  @action
  updatevalue(value) {
    //how to access test button, and change its title?
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `on` modifier is short for `addEventListener` / `removeEventListener`, so clicking the button, once `on` is used on the button, the event handler receives a `MouseEvent`

So,

```
  @action
  handleClick(event) {
    event.target // the button
  }

  @action
  updatevalue(event /* not value */) {
    event.target // the input
  }
```

```
<button type="button" {{on 'click' this.handleClick}}>test</button>
```

Here is a [live demo](https://limber.glimdown.com/edit?c=MQAgMglgtgRgpgJxAUQCYQC4HsEChfCgDqmAFiAFICGAblQMoDGCEADhvo1qnCAGZwAdo14YqAcwDOIRlUEh4IAK6S4qENhDoEcRhgA2ATxA7BPJFyissgoRkkAaXFWkB3OPv0gXJoeY2kvFw8IJKCbKxwGAG8%2BhA0QdyJUHDSfAhYUAB0%2BADy7BA2kgBc%2BAC0IAAGcQmVIBUA%2Bqbm0hDyrPpUIg24FdXxvKw6NBBwrnVNfoit7Z0iDiAdXW3iMaFYSggi3nwYiGs1vM2IPX2Hi8OjrgoeWOMgk2bTIG2Lc3ALS4wrBwO%2BT0h4Po7mtJBstnAerhKjDxAAraTnIZwEZjXDQawIaIAYUy1lsgmi6UyIAA5AABcRxKApBAAeks%2BLspIA3OirDhogBvDQILoAazUIAAvvwMlAyZTqbS6Rg%2BYx%2BStWezMdyQDYRWKSRS4LBEHSoNwIHxRghlbg4AAPVVaOB8KhKfTRRidSTSAASHmBRBw%2BnUVr2ZmkuI5BO5uBAIHJcoFQq4SkJIAAvCAAAxsiMvYQ6FKJlMAChRdgAlMmAHwgLmZyNcQRg-RwLLA8SFhKErJiBDiKLFtmRyMYUgQSRZeOJgDUKYAjH2RfhIwAePZWTp7MvVkAL1hlgCaGxApFoQTiCqFg94MCUGGw8i5XMHw9HG0JwtFGGgqSyC7p2-n-YXl7Xhqd4agARC6EAKqBASPm0zC6nYr5ltiJ78t%2BgE3uui6yrqSxrrgwrQjCuBAA&format=glimdown)

References:

- https://tutorial.glimdown.com
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target